# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (5 > number of parameters, which is 4)

Tags: java, mysql, parameters

```
try{
    String query="insert into result(std_id,exam_id,date,score,status) values(?,?,?,?,?);";
    PreparedStatement pstmt=DatabaseConnector.getPreparedStatement(query);
    pstmt.setInt(1,rd.getStd_id());
    pstmt.setInt(2,rd.getEx_id());
    pstmt.setString(3,rd.getDate());
    pstmt.setDouble(4,rd.getScore());
    pstmt.setInt(5,rd.getStatus());
    **int i=pstmt.executeUpdate();** //error line line 31
    if(i==1){
        result=Results.SUCCESS;
    }
    else
        result=Results.FAILURE;
}
```

The parameter list seems proper but still shows the above error....

Comment: format your code properly....

Comment: Exception it self shows that "result" Accepts 4 inputs params but you are passing 5

Comment: Are you certain that this is the code you actually ran, which generated the error?  I see five wildcards and the code looks OK to me, at least at a glance.

Comment: Where is `getPreparedStatement` defined?

Comment: Too lazy to check, but are parameters indexed from 1 or 0? If indeed from 1 as your code is suggesting than that's a weird design decision by the JDBC guys AFAIC.

Comment: @StijndeWitt I was thinking this, but the error apparently says expecting 4 parameters, so then I questioned the code paste itself.

Comment: If you never tried [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/), do so now, before diving deeper into the JDBC mess. JOOQ is what JDBC should have been imho.

Comment: Can you post the table structure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah you are probably right. Code looks fine except for weird indexing starting at 1... But JDBC is weird so it might be correct  :)

Comment: @StijndeWitt That's not weird, that's correct for JDBC prepared statements.

Comment: I find it weird since every other structure/library in Java starts indexing at 0. :)

Comment: You will get this error when you call any of the setXxx() methods on PreparedStatement, while the SQL query string does not have any placeholders ? for this.

Also This may be an issue with the jdbc Driver version MySql

Comment: @Assen could you please elaborate...bcoz i have used 5 wildcard characters...and so I am passing 5 params...

Comment: @SoumyaDas using mysql-connector-java-5.1.23

Comment: Can please change date name column to other name according to @Alok Singh

Comment: changed column name...its working now...thanku all....

Answer (score 0):

Your column name **"date"** generate ambiguity because date is data type in database.
change name of column and it works.

Comment: Yes, This is the issue.
(5 > number of parameters, which is 4)